# Where to put connectionstring in 3-project solution?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, breeze

I'm trying to create my first Breeze application, here's my project structure:
[image]

As you see I'm trying to keep my solution in 3 layers/projects (I'm used to a single project/layer).
What I don't get is where I put my connectionstring (I wanna use localdb). In a web.config file obviously but where do I put this file?

Furthermore, Breeze is apparently looking for an .mdf file in LM.Web/App_Data - shouldn't my database reside in the project "LM.Model" ?

If anyone has tried this before, could you please give me some pointers?

Comment: If you are going to reuse your class library across other application, keep it in App.Config else, keep it in web application's web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always put your connection string into the Web.config of your startup project, in your case, LM.Web.
In case you will be writing unit tests in the future, put your connection string into the unit test project also, into an App.config file.

Also if you are using a local database and the third party library you are using requires you to put the db file into LM.Web/App_Data, do so. Your DataAccess dll's job is to retrieve and manipulate data, but not to hold it.

Comment: Hi ngergo6 and thanks for your reply!
I've added the connection string to the web.config file of LM.Web and then I created the App_Data folder. The connection works now so I'm quite happy now. Thanks a lot for your help - it means a lot to me :)